# Grab current user ID with facebook-android API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

With Graph API for Android I can get the current user stuff with "/me" calls.

Until here, everything is fine, but I can't find a way to grab the user real ID (numbers)? How can to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`/me` returns a JSON object with an id field (and others). You can parse this JSON object like this:

```
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me", params));
String userId = json.getString("id");
```

Comment: Origin of `Util` class?